# XML parse blocking page load

Tags: xml, parsing, xmlhttprequest, document.write

I'm using the following script to parse an XML document and display it on a website, this all works great, but I have this script inline in the middle of my html document.

It seems to be blocking my page loading by about 300ms so I wanted to put it at the end of the document to fix this issue.

So my question is... How can I have this script at the end of the document, but still display the output in the middle of the document.

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET", "abc.xml", false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("xr")[0].attributes;
att = x.getNamedItem("value");
document.write(att.value);
</script>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind making an onclick function...

```
<body>
    <div onclick="showXML()">Click here to show XML</div>
    </body>
    <script>
    function showXML(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "abc.xml", false);
    xhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("xr")[0].attributes;
    att = x.getNamedItem("value");
    document.write(att.value);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It would need to be and on load rather than an onclick i'm afraid, I am using jquery on the site if that helps with $( document ).ready()   thanks

Comment: Wait,so have you solved it?Or are you asking how to do this with onload and $( document ).ready() @user2201059?

Comment: No I havn't solved it, so please if you can show me how to do it with that method (or any other onload method), it would be great ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery library, you could try the following ([putting the script at the bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)):

```
<body>
    <div id="test">Click here to show XML</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           function showXML(){
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              } else {
                 xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
              xhttp.open("GET", "abc.xml", false);
              xhttp.send();
              xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
              x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("xr")[0].attributes;
              att = x.getNamedItem("value");
              document.write(att.value);
           }
           $("#test").on('click', function(){
              showXML();
           });
       });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How could I use this method without the on click ? Ideally I would want it to load and display automatically, but not block the page loading.. thanks